# Show all button on finder

Tags: macos, finder

On Finder, using the View as Icons grouped by document type, is it possible to visualize all the elements instead of to have to click every time on "Show All" button?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending how many Folders/Files you have it is sometimes not possible to show all to fit in the screen.

You could try to reduce the Icon size (the slider at bottom right of the Finder widow), that helps to see more (or sometimes all) while loosing Icon clarity.